# Jmeter is skipping if controller during script execution

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have created one jmeter script in which there are three flow stages - Start flow, edit flow and revise flow.

I have extracted the status for this flow from one of pre-request using JSON extractor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt9r4.jpg)

I also added three if controller for each flow and added respective flow's requests inside the if controller

Start flow : ${declarationStatus} == "null"

Edit flow :  ${declarationStatus} == "PREPARE"

Revise flow : ${declarationStatus} == "PROCESS"

and then have added some transaction controller after if controllers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpgx6.jpg)

But while executing the script flow , jmeter is skipping IF controller execution and executing transaction controller ( request added in transaction controller) after IF controller.

In script, all requests are getting executed excluding if controller's request.

How can I execute the flow based on the value extracted?

I added debug sampler in script, value is properly extracted but if controller is not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8OP9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not "skipping" the If Controller, it's your expression which supposed to be a [JMeter Function or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) doesn't evaluate to `true`

Try wrapping it into i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) like:

```
${__jexl3( ${declarationStatus} == "PREPARE",)}
```

and JMeter will not "skip" your If Controller anymore.

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller)

Comment: I really appreciate your prompt response! I tested using the __jexl3() function, and it was successful. The script is now running correctly.
Once again, thank you very much!